# getPlace() gives Undefined for dynamically added text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have a text input dynamically added on click and on input change event I need to fetch google api **getPlace()** values.

On enter key hit this works fine but when I select from **mouse** `mouseclick` the `place_changed` event gives place as undefined

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8GnZB/103/)**

```
<div id="clkDIv">CLICK ME</div>
<br>
<div id="contentDiv"></div>
```

---

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759), new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
    $("#clkDIv").on('click', function () {
        var txtEl = "<input id='txtDynamic'  type='text' />";
        $("#contentDiv").append(txtEl);
    });

    $("#contentDiv").on('input', '#txtDynamic', function () {
        $myInput = $(this);
        var options = {
            bounds: defaultBounds,
            types: ['geocode']
        };
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($myInput.get(0), options);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(place);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The autocomplete `place_changed` event listener already takes care of listening to both `Enter` key press **and** click, so you can do it the other way around.

1. Add your input dynamically
2. Bind the autocomplete to your input (after you added it)

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#clkDIv").on('click', function () {
        var txtEl = "<input id='txtDynamic'  type='text' />";
        $("#contentDiv").append(txtEl);

        bindAutocomplete();
    });
});

function bindAutocomplete() {

    var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759), new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

    var options = {
        bounds: defaultBounds,
        types: ['geocode']
    };

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtDynamic'), options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        console.log(place);
    });
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle:

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/8GnZB/106/)</kbd>